# Android Notification bar

Tags: android

I have a test project which is having Junit test cases.

I have a test case where I need to access the notification bar and click on the message that has arrived overthe internet to my application.

How can i do this.
How can I click on the notification message in the notification bar?

Answer (score 1):

this is an example refer this one

```
    public class SimpleNotification extends Activity {

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.android,"New Alert, Click Me!",System.currentTimeMillis());


    Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.notifyButton);
    Button cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification Details...";
            CharSequence contentText = "Browse Android Official Site by clicking me";
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.android.com"));
            PendingIntent intent = 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, 0, 
                notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
        }
    });
}
```

}